# Showing additional marker in google map through ajax

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a google map using "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3". In that map I am showing markers for different locations, which is working fine. Below is the code which i have used.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
                      zoom: 10,
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.42323, -45.47653),

                            });
});
```

Now I want to add some more location markers in Ajax. For ex: I will add the location name from a dropdown, it will do an ajax call to the server side. Pull out the location latitude and longitude and will show in the map. How can i achieve it.

I have written a separate js function to do the ajax call, but inside that the code is not getting 'map' instance.Here I have used only this code

```
    new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.42323, -45.47653),
});
```

Here I am not initializing the map again. So its not getting the map instance and throwing error. How to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your map is limited to inside your event handle. Try this:

```
var map, markerCollection;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
});

function addMarker(lat, lng){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    });
    markerCollection.push(marker);
}
```

NOTES:
1) Be to fill in the values for "latitude" and "longitude" when defining the center of your map. Otherwise you just would get a map displayed.
2) I know it might not be the best practice to add your markers into an array but I find this makes than easy to access latter.

Comment: Hey xion can u pls tell me where should i keep the upper part of the code i.e code written above addMarker(), and where to keep the below part. coz currently i have kept the map initialization inside document.ready() and addmarker() outside of document.ready().

Comment: by placing the code 'var map' outside of the event handle it turns the scope of that variable to Global. This will allow you to call 'map' any where in your javascript. I don't know how your ajax works but this should be your workflow: 1) Page loads, 2) DOM Listener is trigered, 3) 'map' is instantiated, 4) Trigger Ajax (you need to give more information or know how to do this yourself), 5) Ajax success calls 'addMarker(lat, lng)' and passes the latitude and longitude values, 6) A marker should appear on your map.

Answer (score 0):

Since `map` is not a global variable it is getting dereferenced. Make the `map` object either global or within a container function that stores all of your code.

#### Global JS example

```
//now it's global
var map;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.42323, -45.47653),
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah, this much of code i have written initially to show the initial markers.  But now i want add some more markers without reloading the page, through an ajax call. For that i have written another js function like add_more_markers(). How can i get the map instance inside this method.

Comment: Just use the `map` variable. It is global.